# how to implement a Multilayer Neural Network in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

```
m1= xlsread('NSL_KDD_TRAIN.xlsx','A2:AO67344'); % m1=input
m= xlsread('NSL_KDD_TRAIN.xlsx','AP2:AP67344'); % m=output

net=newff(m1',m',8);  
net=train(net,m1',m');
y=sim(net,m1');  %training data output
y3=round(y);   % making nonfraction number

n1= xlsread('NSL_KDD_TRAIN.xlsx','A67345:AO79000'); % n1=input
n= xlsread('NSL_KDD_TRAIN.xlsx','AP67345:AP79000'); % n=output

net=newff(n1',n',8);
net=train(net,n1',n');
y1=sim(net,n1');  %training data output
y31=round(y1);
```

i want to use the outputs of feed forward neural networks as input for training another same kind of neural network. how can i do that using built-in function?,from the above code i need to train a new `newff` where my input arguments will be `y3` and `y31`. in `m1` and `n1` a have 41 columns  and i need all 41 columns presence in the new network. how can i do that using built-in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use two layers and train just one network if you assume architecture is the same?

```
net = newff(input,target,[Layer_1 Layer_2],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig'});
```

You can specify the size of Layer_1 and Layer_2 as much as you want as well as you can change activation function between each of the layers.

[Tutorial to create custom network from Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/network.html)

Hope this will help